# View Git History in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I can only view Local History in Android Studio. How do I view git history?

I have already checked out my project using Git into Android Studio.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

While writing this question I found the answer, I thought it maybe useful to someone else stuck like I was.

If you go to **VCS => Enable Version Control Integration**

You can then selected **Git** or your version control.

To view Git history all you need to do now is secondary click on the code in AS and select **Git => Show History**

Comment: Is there any shortcut to get Git history in Android Studio??

Comment: @MANISHPATHAK Preferences > KeyMap > search "show history" > scroll and find "git" under you'll find "show history" > right click > click "Add keyboard shortcut" select your shortcut.

Comment: @JakeGrahamArnold I am not getting "Enable Version Control Integration" option in VCS tab in my latest andrdoid studio v2.2.2. Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: @farhan can you share a screenshot of what you do see (under VCS)?

Comment: What is the command line code on the terminal? I would like to do this automatically from Terminal.

Answer (score 15):

Thanks to @JakeGrahamArnold solution, it is simply `VCS > Git > Show History` or Toolbar

[image]

---

In [new UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74685382/how-to-enable-android-studio-new-ui) [theme](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/new-ui.html) this icon has been removed. In order to show it you can do one of this:

1. Press menu > Git > Current File > Show History.
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> (near <kbd>1</kbd>), select `Show History`.

[image]

3. Add the icon to the toolbar.

- right click in the Toolbar, press `Customize Toolbar...`,

[image]

- press `+` and `Add Action...`,

[image]

- Expand tree: Version Control Systems > Git, select `Show History`, press `OK`, `Apply`.

[image]

Comment: is this icon, removed in the Android Studio 'New UI' theme?

Comment: @Jovin, yes. Thanks, I updated the answer.

Comment: nice answer for new UI theme