# How to enable Android Studio new ui

Tags: android-studio

How to enable will Android Studio get new UI like IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3?

Comment: You should move your edit to an answer below…

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Update Edit : Android Studio Graffie version settings

[image: Android Studio New ui]

Update Edit : Android Studio Flamingo version is stable. You can use the following settings again.

Update Edit : currently it only works on Android Studio 2022.2.1 (Flamingo) from Canary channel.

- Go to the actions dropdown menu:

  - for Windows/Linux: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
  - for Mac OS: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
- Search for Registry.
- Type "ide.experimental" (even if there is no search bar at the moment).
- Check "ide.experimental.ui", "ide.experimental.ui.scroll" and "ide.experimental.ui.inter.font".
- Restart as suggested.
- Here you go, you can now use this new minimalistic and wonderful user interface, please have fun!

[image: Android Studio new ui]

Comment: it doesn't work on latest stable 2021.3.1, after enable "ide.experimental.ui" and others it only changed the icons with new ui icons, but nothing more changed, all other views looks same as always.
Also tried on 2022.1.1 RC3, it doesn't work also the checkbox for "ide.experimental.ui" have a warning icon, and even icons not work anything of new ui

Comment: Sadly, this doesn’t seem to work anymore (Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1 Build #AI-213.7172.25.2113.9123335)

Comment: Android studio preview must be installed.

Comment: can you edit the answer and add the android studio minimal version requirement?
currently it only works on Android Studio 2022.2.1 (Flamingo) from Canary channel.

Comment: checking "ide.experimental.ui" is enough as per its description : "When enabled all experimental ui keys will be treated as true
Requires an IDE restart"

Comment: This worked just fine for me in Flamingo in the stable channel! Thanks! :D

Comment: It works and it's awesome. Thanks a lot OP ❤️, plus I've learned about the registry… something I didn't know about.

Answer (score 2):

**A New Intellij IDEA UI - Preview.**

Go to "**Appearence & Behavior > New UI > Enable new UI**".

***Better than the old design? :)***

[image: New UI Preview]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#new-ui-preview

Official Link

Comment: Android Studio Giraffe version is required.

Comment: Yes, you have to use Giraffe Version

Comment: This option seems to be gone in Flamingo. Unfortunately an update leaves the "new" Ui partly behind, breaking quite some things. Only manipulating the registry worked for me

Answer (score 2):

**Fresh Answer**

Follow steps: *Android Studio* --> *Settings...* --> *Appearance & Behaviour* --> *New UI (Beta)* --> Select "*Enable new UI*" option --> Click "*Apply*" --> Done!

[image]

Comment: what android studio version your using

Comment: @TippuFisalSheriff my android studio version is: Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Beta 5, built on June 6, 2023.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't see `New UI` option in your Appearance settings, You can
Go to Help | Find Action | Registry, and start typing the key name for ide.experimental.ui, then enable it. Then, restart the IDE.